# Smallest positive root of $\tan(x) - x$

Tags: calculus

The smallest positive root of $\tan(x)-x=0$ lies in?

Considering $f(x)  = \tan(x)-x$  to be a function, then differentiaing it, I get $f'(x) = \tan^2(x)$. This implies it's an increasing function. So shouldn't $f(x) =0$ for $x > 0$ be impossible because at $x=0$  the function is zero?

Comment: *Hint:* $f(x)$ is increasing in each *interval* where it is defined. What happens beyond $\frac \pi 2$ ?

Comment: After x=π/2, tanx starts increasing from (-∞ to ∞)and x is increasing like always

Comment: So it would make sense for them to intersect here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion “$f' > 0 \implies f$ is increasing” is only valid on *intervals* where $f$ is defined.

In your case, $f(x) = \tan x - x$ is defined on all intervals
$$
 I_k = \{ x \in \Bbb R, \frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2} < x < \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2} \}
$$
with $k \in \Bbb Z$. Within each interval $I_k$, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, and approaches $-\infty$ at the left boundary, and $+\infty$ at the right boundary of the interval.

From this you can conclude that $f(x)$ has (exactly) one root in each $I_k$. As you correctly observed, $x=0$ is the only root in $I_0$. Therefore the smallest positive root is in the interval $I_1 = (\pi/2, 3 \pi/2)$.